# Si coloco carácter especial no valida mayúsculas ni minusculas - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Como en mi pregunta anterior estoy haciendo un curso desde cero en Javascript. Actualmente debo hacer un validador de contraseña. Todo al parecer funcionaba bien, pero cuando coloco un carácter especial no funciona la validación de las mayúsculas y minúsculas. No soy muy diestro con esta herramienta y por más que leo el código no consigo el error, a continuación el código:

```html
<script>
var input = 'ASDASSSD!';
var specialCharacters = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*'];

function isPasswordValid(input){
  if (hasUpperCase(input) && hasLowerCase(input) && isLongEnough(input) && hasSpecialCharacter(input)){
    console.log('La contrasena es valida');
  }else if(!hasUpperCase(input)){
    console.log('Al menos una letra mayuscula');
  }else if(!hasLowerCase(input)){
    console.log('Al menos una letra minuscula');
  }else if (!isLongEnough(input)){
    console.log('Al menos 8 caracteres');
  }else if (!hasSpecialCharacter(input)){
    console.log('Al menos un caracter especial');
  }
}

function hasUpperCase(input){
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    if (input[i] === input[i].toUpperCase()){
      return true;
    }
  }
}

function hasLowerCase(input){
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    if (input[i] === input[i].toLowerCase()){
      return true;
    }
  }
}

function isLongEnough(input){
  if(input.length >= 8){
    return true;
  }
}

function hasSpecialCharacter(input){
  for(var k = 0; k < input.length; k++){
    for(var i = 0; i < specialCharacters.length; i++){
      if(input[k]===specialCharacters[i]){
        return true;
      }
    }
    
  }
  
}

//hasSpecialCharacter(input);
isPasswordValid(input);
hasUpperCase(input);
</script>
```

**Lo ultimo que pude validar es que la función .toUpperCase y toLowerCase detectan a los caracteres especiales como mayúsculas y minúsculas he ahí el problema, creo que debo hallar otra función.**

Answer (score 0):

Bueno realmente tu codigo esta funcionando correctamente ya que los simbolos en mayusculas o minusculas son iguales al igual que los numeros y entonces lo que deberias usar son expresiones regulares u omitir los números y símbolos cuando revises las mayúsculas o minúsculas

Hice un ejemplo trantando de usar codigo simple y casi el mismo que el tuyo
una expresión regular basicamente es lo contenido en **[ ]** 
por ejemplo en **[a-zñáéíóú]** dice es de la **a** hasta la **z** , la **ñ** y las letras acentuadas tambien estan incluidas

Aun así deberías revisar esto
[Expresiones regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

```html
<script>
var input = 'ASaDxSD!';

  const regularExpresion = {
    "lower": /^[a-zñáéióú]+$/,
    "upper": /^[A-ZÑÁÉÍÓÚ]+$/,
    "specialCharacters": /^[!@#$%^&*+]$/,
    "numbers": /^[0-9]$/
  }

function isPasswordValid(input){
  if (hasUpperCase(input) && hasLowerCase(input) && isLongEnough(input) && hasSpecialCharacter(input)){
    console.log('La contrasena es valida');
  }else if(!hasUpperCase(input)){
    console.log('Al menos una letra mayuscula');
  }else if(!hasLowerCase(input)){
    console.log('Al menos una letra minuscula');
  }else if (!isLongEnough(input)){
    console.log('Al menos 8 caracteres');
  }else if (!hasSpecialCharacter(input)){
    console.log('Al menos un caracter especial');
  }
}

function hasUpperCase(input){
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
     if (regularExpresion.upper.test(input[i])) {
  return true;
     }
  }
  return false;
}

function hasLowerCase(input){
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
     if (regularExpresion.lower.test(input[i])) {
  return true;
     }
  }
  return false;
}

function isLongEnough(input){
  if(input.length >= 8){
    return true;
  }
}

function hasSpecialCharacter(input){
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
     if (regularExpresion.specialCharacters.test(input[i])) {
  return true;
     }
  }
  return false;
  
}

isPasswordValid(input);

  </script>
```